# Is there a JavaScript/discord.js function that lets you edit hex values?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been developing a Discord bot lately and I've been wondering if I can use discord.js to edit specific hex values for files requested by users (.mp4, .mov and .webm) and how to do it. I'm very new to JavaScript and developing Discord bots (started a day ago) so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by hex values?

Comment: Sorry for being 7 months late, but when you change hex in a hex editor to change metadata. Here's an example of what i'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHQ7dW6M2s